# Id is lost while trying to JSON.stringify Ember model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to `JSON.stringify()` the model of a route inside the controller by using the below code. It works and it returns all model attributes, except for the actual id of the model. Can we receive the id as well?

```
    var plan = this.get('model');
    var reqBody = JSON.stringify(
                                 {
                                    plan,
                                    token
                                 });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass in the `includeId` option to the [toJSON method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON) in order to get the ID in the JSON.

```
var plan = this.get('model');
var reqBody = JSON.stringify({
    plan: plan.toJSON({ includeId: true }),
    token
});
```

And if you didn't know, `JSON.stringify()` will [call `toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) for you (which is what is happening in your case). If you want to call `JSON.stringify()` instead of `model.toJSON({})`, you can always override it:

```
App.Plan = DS.Model.extend({
    toJSON: function() {
        return this._super({ includeId: true });
    }
});
```

That way `JSON.stringify(plan)` will give you exactly what you want.

Comment: Liked the 2nd method as it has global effect. But good to know both versions exist.